# I'm getting the following error while using PyInstaller: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyinstaller, ubuntu-15.04

The PyInstaller version is 3.1 and I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with a 64 bit processor.

Here is the entire traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 755, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 701, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 432, in assemble
    imphook_object = ImportHook(imported_name, hook_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._module = importlib_load_source(hook_modname, self._filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py", line 36, in <module>
    cachedata = subprocess.check_output('gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

I was able to successfully compile a small hello world type app with Pyinstaller. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As you haven't posted any code its difficult to tell what has caused this, however the last line of the traceback indicates a missing file/folder `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

Comment: The code is over 2000 lines long. I was hoping someone familiar with Pyinstaller could tell me what the errors mean. The traceback occurred while compiling the Python script with Pyinstaller (pyinstaller myapp.py)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong with it? Running in to similar problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the problem by downgrading setup tools to version 2.9. I found the answer on another post but it's been a long time ago so I'm not sure who to credit.